# Is it possible to include table name from @Table annotation in Javadoc

Tags: java, maven, jpa, annotations, javadoc

I'm using maven to generate javadoc on an application that has 50+ entity beans. All entities use the javax.persistence.Table anntotaion with the table name defined like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT", catalog="MYSCHEMA",uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="ACCOUNTID")
})
```

Is there any way to tell mavens javadoc plugin to display all or some of the @table details?